# Access current row value (Table Edit mode)

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to get a query up but this doesn't work.
I have t

In the edit mode, i want a Choice List to be filtered depending on the value of the column on the left.
I edit the SQL query, but what is the command to access the current row value of the field on the left?

Thanks guys :D

Comment: Do you have a table or query open in Datasheet view? Or is this a form?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a table or query, I'm not sure that this is possible. The query you enter into the RecordSource property is running independently of the Datasheet view of the table/query you are currently in.

If this is a form, then you can refer to the value of a form control for the current record as follows:

```
Forms!FormName!FormControl
```